# How to obtain this Generalized Hölder inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am reading some scientific papers in physics, where the author gave the Hölder inequality in this form:

[image]

and I am struggling on how to derive it from the usual Hölder inequality:

[image]

any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit simpler than  Hölder's inequality; this is a special case of [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for convex functions. Indeed, since $\sum P_i=1$ and the function $f(x) = x^{r/r'}$ is convex, the inequality says that for any positive numbers $x_i$, 
$$
\sum P_i f(x_i) \ge f\left(\sum P_i x_i\right) \tag{1}
$$
With the choice $x_i = P_i^{r'}$ this becomes 
$$
\sum P_i P_i^r \ge \left(\sum P_i P_i^{r'}\right)^{r/r'} \tag{2}
$$
which is the inequality you wanted.

---

You can also obtain this the Hölder way, via 
$$
\sum_i x_i y_i P_i \le \left(\sum_i x_i^p  P_i\right)^{1/p}\left(\sum_i y_i^q  P_i\right)^{1/q} \tag{3}
$$
where $P_i\ge 0$. The presence of the weights $P_i$ is what makes this the *generalized* Hölder's inequality. I don't think there's a neat way to get it from the standard form; it's easier to prove it directly by following the proof of the standard Hölder's inequality.

In (3), you would put $x_i=1$, $y_i=P_i^{r'}$, and $q=r/r'$.